# Найти и удалить одинаковые слова в std::string

Tags: c++, строки

Ввести 2 предложения, а затем исключить слова во втором предложении, которые имеются в первом. После чего вывести полученное второе предложение.

Смог сделать только удаление первого предложения. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    string non;

    getline(cin, non);
    int i;
    int b = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= non.length(); i++) {
        if (non.at(i) == '.') {
            break;
        }
        b++;
    }
       b = b + 2;
    cout << b << endl;
    non.erase(0, b);

    cout << non;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что делать со знаками препинания после удаления каких-то слов.

Answer (score 0):

```js
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
string first;
string second;
string newStr = "";
string buf = "";
getline(cin, first);
int i = first.find(".");
second = first.substr(0, i);
for (i++; i < first.length(); i++) {
 if (first[i] != ' ') {

  buf += first[i];
 }


 if (first[i] == ' ' || i == first.length() - 1) {

  if (second.find(buf) == std::string::npos && buf != " ") {
   newStr += buf + ' ';
   buf = "";

  }
  else { buf = ""; }
 }
}
cout << newStr;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Думаю можно лучше придумать, но пока как есть )
Если нужны будут комментарии, отпишите

Comment: Спасибо, но вся проблема, что оба предложения должны находится в одном стринге

Comment: Они должны разделяться точкой ? Или переходом на новую строку ?

Comment: 2 предложения в одном  стринге, разделённые точкой

Comment: Все сделал, так ?

Comment: Да, спасибо вам большое

Comment: Не за что ) Обращайтесь ) И стрелочку , если ответ вам действительно помог, пожалуйста , удачи )

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// Ввести 2 предложения, а затем исключить слова во втором предложении,
// которые имеются в первом. После чего вывести полученное второе предложение.

using str_vector_t = std::vector<std::string>;

template<template<typename...> typename Container, typename T>
bool contains(const Container<T>& c, const T& value) {
    return c.cend() != std::find_if(c.cbegin(), c.cend(), [&](const T& ref_value) {
        return ref_value == value;
    });
}

void split_string(const std::string& sentence, str_vector_t& words);

int main() {
    const auto sentence_f = "Show me you are a big boy";
    const auto sentence_s = "Let me stop you there big boy";    // me you big boy

    str_vector_t words_f, words_s;

    split_string(sentence_f, words_f);
    split_string(sentence_s, words_s);

    words_s.erase(
        std::remove_if(words_s.begin(), words_s.end(), [&](const auto& word_s) {
            return contains(words_f, word_s);
        }), words_s.end());

    std::cout << "Result: ";
    for (const auto& word : words_s)
        std::cout << word << ' ';

    return 0;
}

void split_string(const std::string& sentence, str_vector_t& words) {
    std::string word;
    std::stringstream stream { sentence };
    while (std::getline(stream, word, ' '))
        words.emplace_back(std::move(word));
};
```